# Tizen Native Genlist Background

Tags: background, tizen, tizen-native-app, efl

I'm developing a Galaxy Gear S2 application that makes use of a genlist to display information. One of the requirements of the application is that the genlist should have a orange background instead of an black one. I have been using [this site](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.guides/html/native/ui/component_background_wn.htm) as guidance.

I have changed the background of the window but the the windows background seems to be behind the genlist background. What this means is that the background color only shows when changing between windows.

The genlist looks as follows.

```
static void create_first_list(appdata_s *ad){
    Evas_Object *genlist = NULL;
    Evas_Object *naviframe = ad ->naviframe;
    Elm_Object_Item *nf_it = NULL;
    Elm_Genlist_Item_Class *itc = elm_genlist_item_class_new();
    Elm_Genlist_Item_Class *titc = elm_genlist_item_class_new();
    Elm_Genlist_Item_Class *pitc = elm_genlist_item_class_new();
    item_data *id = NULL;
    int index = 0;

    local_ad = ad;

    genlist = elm_genlist_add(naviframe);
    elm_genlist_mode_set(genlist, ELM_LIST_COMPRESS);
    evas_object_smart_callback_add(genlist, "selected", NULL, NULL);

    ad->circle_genlist = eext_circle_object_genlist_add(genlist, ad->circle_surface);
    eext_circle_object_genlist_scroller_policy_set(ad->circle_genlist, ELM_SCROLLER_POLICY_OFF, ELM_SCROLLER_POLICY_AUTO);
    eext_rotary_object_event_activated_set(ad->circle_genlist, EINA_TRUE);

    itc->item_style = "1text";
    itc->func.text_get = _gl_main_text_getfirst;
    itc->func.del = _gl_menu_del;
    titc->item_style = "title";
    titc->func.text_get = _gl_title_text_get;
    titc->func.del = _gl_menu_del;
    pitc->item_style = "padding";
    elm_genlist_item_append(genlist, titc, NULL, NULL, ELM_GENLIST_ITEM_NONE, NULL, ad);
    id = calloc(sizeof(item_data), 1);
    id->index = index++;
    id->item = elm_genlist_item_append(genlist, itc, id, NULL, ELM_GENLIST_ITEM_NONE, btn_cb_connect, ad);
    elm_genlist_item_append(genlist, pitc, NULL, NULL, ELM_GENLIST_ITEM_NONE, NULL, ad);


    elm_genlist_item_class_free(titc);
    elm_genlist_item_class_free(itc);
    elm_genlist_item_class_free(pitc);
    local_ad->naviframe = naviframe;

    nf_it = elm_naviframe_item_push(naviframe, NULL, NULL, NULL, genlist, "empty");
    elm_naviframe_item_pop_cb_set(nf_it, _naviframe_pop_cb, ad->win);
}
```

This genlist only contains one item in it. I have attemped to change the background color by performing the following in the genlist generating method.

> elm_bg_color_set(genlist, 255, 168, 0);

This does not work to change the background of the genlist. Is there a way to change the entire genlist background? If so, how?

Comment: What are you doing in `create_list_view()`? That seems the most relevant part.

Comment: @ozbek That is where the first genlist is created and added to the naviframe.

Comment: do you see the background color change if you remove `create_list_view(ad);`?

Comment: @ozbek the background color does change, but that means that the genlist is not displayed. It seems like the genslist is covering the background

Comment: yes, that's why I was saying probably you have not posted the most relevant part of the code :)

Comment: @ozbek I added the code for `create_list_view(ad)`

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom genlist style:

```
collections {
images {
    image: "bg.png" COMP;
}
group {
    name: "elm/genlist/base/custom";
    parts {
        part { // Here you can set solid bg color
            name: "bg";
            type: RECT;
            description {
                color: 231 232 142 255; 
            }
        }
        part { // And any image as bg here
            name: "bg_image";
            type: IMAGE;
            description {
                image.normal: "bg.png"; 
            }
        }
        part {
            name: "pd.top";
            type: SPACER;
            description {
                min: 0 30;
                max: -1 30;
                fixed: 0 1;
                align: 0.5 0.0;
            }
        }
        part {
            name: "elm.swallow.content";
            type: SWALLOW;
            description {
                rel1 {
                    relative: 0.0 1.0;
                    to_y: "pd.top";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Extend default theme with the style:

```
elm_theme_extension_add(NULL, "path_to_file_containing_custom_style.edj");
```

And apply to genlist:

```
elm_object_style_set(genlist, "custom");
```

Answer (score -1):

You create Background Elementary Widget with `elm_bg_add()` but you did not set it visible.

And If you created window with `elm_win_util_standard_add()`. default background was created already in window.

So use `elm_win_add()` and `elm_bg_add()` separately.

Following code is implementation of `elm_win_util_standard_add()`.
Just do like this code and change color of `bg`.

```
EAPI Evas_Object *
elm_win_util_standard_add(const char *name, const char *title)
{
   Evas_Object *win, *bg;

   win = elm_win_add(NULL, name, ELM_WIN_BASIC);
   if (!win) return NULL;

   elm_win_title_set(win, title);
   bg = elm_bg_add(win);
   if (!bg)
     {
        evas_object_del(win);
        return NULL;
     }
   evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(bg, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
   elm_win_resize_object_add(win, bg);
   evas_object_show(bg);

   return win;
}
```

Comment: This works great for setting the background color of the window, so when changing windows it flashes the color. But it does not change the background of the genlist. Is it even possible to change the background color of an entire genlist?